# Python:JS: How to parse multiple kml node in one xml file?

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

```
<xml>
    <mapshape title="Bar" extras="">
    <kml></kml>
    </mapshape>

    <mapshape title="Foo" extras="">
    <kml></kml>
    </mapshape>
</xml>
```

I've got a xml doc like that, multiple mapshape nodes in one xml, and each contains one valid kml file. I need to plot them all on google maps.

I have tried libraries like geoxml(3), they can parse one kml file, but my document has many kmls, how can I deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lxml to extract the kml sections and then pass them on to the other library:

```
doc = """<xml>
    <mapshape title="Bar" extras="">
    <kml></kml>
    </mapshape>

    <mapshape title="Foo" extras="">
    <kml></kml>
    </mapshape>
</xml>"""

import lxml.etree as etree

xml = etree.fromstring(doc)
for mapshape in xml:
    kml = etree.tostring(mapshape.getchildren()[0])
    parseKML(kml)
```